# Django.Адаптивная мобильная версия

Tags: css, django, mobile

Возникла идея сделать мобильную версию для сайта, который написан на Django 1.8
Прочесал немного гугл и почти не нашел достойного гайда или описания по верстке.. в основном одна вода, общая информация и советы для wordpress...
Я так понимаю, достаточно понимать что прописать в CSS и просто добавить в html строку с распознаванием устройства.

1.Вопрос: нормально ли реагирует Django на адаптивную верстку?

2. Подскажите пожалуйста какой-нибудь блог или гайд с примерами кода.
3. Пожелания, советы?

Comment: Вы хотите отдельную версию для мобильных устройств или хотите чтоб основная версия на мобильных отображалась иначе?

Comment: 2-ой вариант хотелось бы (как самый простой)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django здесь ни при чем, потому что Django - это инструмент, который работает на сервере, а верстка - это то, что формируется браузером у пользователя. Вы можете делать шаблоны для Django, которые могут быть как адаптивными, так и нет, все зависит от Вас. Нет какой-то магической команды, которая бы разом преобразовывала шаблон из неадаптивного в адаптивный.

Могу посоветовать книгу Бена Фрейна ["HTML5 и CSS3.Разработка сайтов для любых браузеров и устройств"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/22435909/), где как раз описывается, как сделать свой сайт адаптивным.

Или Вы хотите сделать принципиально разные сайты для мобильных устройств и компьютеров?

Comment: Я как раз хочу использовать метод с адаптивным дизайном. Спасибо за книгу. В догонку вопрос: насколько сложно на Ваш взгляд создать такой дизайн этим методом?

Comment: Повозиться, конечно, придется, но ничего сверхестественного в этом нет.

Comment: Это не так.
Я вот тоже так думал, но сейчас столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой у Flask.
Браузер НЕ ЧИТАЕТ мобильную вёрстку страниц при выдаче через flask, хотя, если эти же страницы открыть просто как html, всё работает отлично.